# Jenssegers/mongodo relations not working after upgrading to Laravel 5.3

Tags: mongodb, laravel-5.3, jenssegers-mongodb

After upgrading to Laravel 5.3, querying hybrid relations relations are throwing an error.

```
FatalErrorException in Builder.php line 613:
Call to a member function all() on array
```

I am using HybridRelations trait, and trying to query a Moloquent model from an Eloquent Model

```
$user->store()->first();
```

Here $user is an Eloquent Model and has a store(Moloquent). While querying this relation, I am getting this error.

Any help?

Comment: I think you should have reported this on the project's issues, but it was posted before this. Here's the report: https://github.com/jenssegers/laravel-mongodb/issues/936

Comment: Yup, that's was me :) Works on version 3.1.0-alpha!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alpha Laravel 5.3 support is available on release >= 3.1.x (currently *3.1.0-alpha*)
So you can simply upgrade dependency version to `3.1.0-alpha` and run `composer update`

Comment: @Parziphal Can you please answer the question posted in stack overflow `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41462510/hasmany-relationship-issue-in-laravel-5-3-mongodb-library-jenssegers-laravel`